# Binding on a port with netpipes/netcat

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, unix

I am trying to write a simple bash script that is listening on a port and responding with a trivial HTTP response. My specific issue is that I am not sure if the port is available and in case of bind failure I fall back to next port until bind succeeds.

So far to me the easiest way to achieve this was something like:

```
for (( i=$PORT_BASE; i < $(($PORT_BASE+$PORT_RANGE)); i++ ))
do
  if [ $DEBUG -eq 1 ] ; then
    echo trying to bind on $i
  fi
  /usr/bin/faucet $i --out --daemon echo test 2>/dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then                        #success?
    port=$i
    if [ $DEBUG -eq 1 ] ; then
      echo "bound on port $port"
    fi
    break
  fi
done
```

Here I am using `faucet` from [netpipes](http://www.purplefrog.com/~thoth/netpipes/netpipes.html) Ubuntu package.

The problem with this is that if I simply print "test" to the output, `curl` complains about non-standard HTTP response (error code 18). That's fair enough as I don't print HTTP-compatible response.

If I replace `echo test` with `echo -ne "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\ntest"`, curl still complains:

```
user@server:$ faucet 10020 --out --daemon echo -ne "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\ntest"
...
user@client:$ curl ip.of.the.server:10020
curl: (56) Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

I think the problem lies in how `faucet` is printing the response and handling the connection. For example if I do the server side in `netcat`, curl works fine:

```
user@server:$ echo -ne "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\ntest\r\n" | nc -l 10020
...
user@client:$ curl ip.of.the.server:10020
test
user@client:$
```

I would be more than happy to replace `faucet` with `netcat` in my main script, but the problem is that I want to spawn independent server process to be able to run client from the same base shell. `faucet` has a very handy `--daemon` parameter as it forks to background and I can use `$?` (exit status code) to check if bind succeeded. If I was to use `netcat` for a similar purpose, I would have to fork it using `&` and `$?` would not work.

Does anybody know why `faucet` isn't responding correctly in this particular case and/or can suggest a solution to this problem. I am not married neither to `faucet` nor `netcat` but would like the solution to be implemented using bash or it's utilities (as opposed to write something in yet another scripting language, such as Perl or Python).

Comment: It's not necessary to use `$(())` inside `(())`: `for (( i=PORT_BASE; i < PORT_BASE+PORT_RANGE; i++ ))`. You should also use `printf` in your `faucet` command since the support for the `-n` and `-e` options for `echo` implementation dependent. Watching traffic with Wireshark I see `faucet` sending `RST` for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for your tips, will modify my script according to your comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
faucet 10020 --out --daemon \
    echo -ne "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 4\r\n\r\ntest"
```

works fine.  The issue seems to be that `echo` doesn't know how to properly `shutdown` a socket, using just `close` instead, and `curl` is unhappy about getting a -1 (disorderly shutdown) rather than a 0 (orderly shutdown) from `recvfrom`.

Try [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) which sticks around to clean up after the child is done.

```
socat tcp-l:10020,fork,reuseaddr \
    exec:'echo -ne "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\ntest"'
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe have a look at the "sock" program of Richard Stevens as well. It has:

```
-F    fork after connection accepted   (TCP concurrent server)
```

http://www.icir.org/christian/sock.html

And using Bash you may also use:

```
echo $'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\ntest\r\n'
```

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like what I needed, although I got the faucet solution working already.

Answer (score 1):

do you really need to use HTTP protocol, or is that just to please curl?  if it's the latter, simply combine

```
 faucet $port --out --daemon echo test
```

with

```
 hose $server $port --in cat
```

Comment: Yes, I need to use HTTP as the end result is to do HTTP proxy monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the program called tcpserver from the DJB ucspi-tcp package.

http://lserinol.blogspot.com/2008/12/simple-tcp-server-with-djb-tcpserver.html

An advanced alternative to netcat or nc respectively is ncat (part of nmap).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but unless I misread their man pages, both tcpserver and ncat are no better than netcat (in my context). The point of my question is to understand why `faucet` fails to respond, or to have an alternative which doesn't require forking from bash (like `faucet` and unlike netcat) so I could check process status.